# Show number of results in each "filter item"

Tags: php, mysql

How can i get the number of each filter item in a seach?

Example... im doing a job/resumes portal... i seach a job title and i have some filters items like City, State , area and etc... How can i show the number of each filter in the select box example Contry: Brazil(22 results), USA(61 results)

Here a url with a sample:
http://www.manager.com.br/resumes/resumes_result.php?&search_table=resumes&tipo_local=0&keyword=program&

Tkz
Roberto

Comment: Your link isn't working. Might help if you posted some code.

Comment: heres a screenshot with the selects box that i talk about : http://yfrog.com/5ytemp1ij

Answer (score 0):

You should get acquainted with GROUP BY clause and count(*) aggregate function:

```
SELECT Country, count(*)
FROM items
GROUP BY Country;
```

And when you have absorbed the necessary minimum, take a look at useful extensions to the GROUP BY clause in MySQL, namely [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

Comment: tkz... ill check this... but its not "too much" to a mysql handling with a lot of options (as screenshot sample) to a search where a lot of people will be using?

Comment: @Roberto: When you develop, you should adjust the database schema to the needs of the business. In any real-world application you will have queries that are complex and slow, but you should understand why they are slow. Sometimes it is rather easy to re-organize your data in a way, that querying them would not be killer to your system.